# Select Rows from a Subset SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates, unique, subset

I need to select the header ID from the below table whose Container IDs does not Duplicate within that header and Tracking ID Set.Tracking IDs should also be unique for a header ID

```
Header ID     Tracking ID      ContainerID
xx            abc                123
xx            def                456
yy            abc                123
yy            def                456
zz            ghi                123
zz            ghi                123
zz            ghi                456
```

Result Set should be like this:

```
Header ID
xx
yy
```

SQL Server

Comment: which database - sql server, mysql, oracle, postgres ???

Comment: you can do it using **Group by**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it is what you want. I used SQL server for this. I won't be around the forum for a while. So, won't be responding to you for some time.

```
select r2.HeaderID
(
select r1.HeaderID, MAX(r1.cont_num) as max_c
from
(
select headerid,count(containerid) as cont_num
from dups
group by HeaderID, containerid
) as r1
group by r1.HeaderID
having MAX(r1.cont_num) = 1
) as r2
```

Comment: I needed only the Header ID column where tracking ID is same but In that subset container ID should be different.We should be eliminating all header ID which has duplicate container IDs...Like the Header ID zz has duplicate Container ID(123)..So zz should be omitted from the Result Set.